# Is there any mention of "Scissors" in the Hindu literature?

Tags: history, culture, tradition

The Goddess Tara is shown holding scissors

[image]

Scissors symbolises that the Goddess cuts asunder the attachments to this material worlds, much feared by the spiritual souls.

Now, scissors looks a bit too modern when thought of to be used by Hindus, especially, the Hindu Gods. Leaving this apart, is it really true that Hindus had scissors? Or is it later addition to Goddess's iconography?

Is there any other mention of scissors, and other more familiar modern tools, which do not suit the Hindu Gods. (Just imagine Narayana using mobile phones. Shiva rejoicing on music on music player. Durga delighting using tablets and laptops. It is so obscene.)

Comment: "Just imagine Narayana using mobile phones. Shiva rejoicing on music on music player. Durga delighting using tablets and laptops."- These technologies are not in accordance with the nature. One must have to harm the nature directly or indirectly to leverage modern technologies is the reason Gods don't use. Earlier things were produced so as not to destroy nature anyhow.

Comment: @Rohit. Haha. Yes. That's why, it looks so indecent. Scissors also look a bit modern type. Like, usually God is shown using Sword to cut the bondages of life. So I was wondering if scissors attributed to Devi is later modern addition or did Hindus really used it.

Comment: This image seems like modern Human creative drawing, but jokes apart Most likely that scissors were invented around 1500 BC in ancient Egypt.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> **Scissors** symbolises that the Goddess cuts asunder the attachments to
>   this material worlds, much feared by the spiritual souls.

The first thing we need to verify is  whether Goddess TAra is at all described in scriptures as holding scissors or not. If we can prove that she is not , then there is no need to answer your remaining questions.

Goddess TAra is the 2nd mAhAvidya. and, here is her dhyAnam from the Nila Tantram :

> PratyAlirapadam ghorAm mundamAlA vibhushitAm |
>   KharvAm lambodarim bhimAm vyAghra charmAvritAm katau ||
>   Nava yauvana sampannAm pancha mudrA vibhusiTam |
>   **ChaturbhujAm lola jihvAm mahAbhimAm vara pradAm || Khadaga kartri samAyukta savyetara bhujadwAm | KapAlotpala samyukta savyetara
>   bhujadwayAm ||**
>
> .......
>   ViswavyApaka toyAntaha swetapadma paristhitAm |
>   Akshobhya devimurddhanya strimurtinAgarupadhrik ||

### Meaning of only the highlighted verses

> Goddess is lolAjihva (tongue hanging out), chaturbhujA (having four
>   hands), mahAbhimA (terrible or extremely powerful) and baradAyini
>   (granter of boons). **Goddess is holding in her right hands khadga ( a
>   sword) and kartrika ( a weapon similar to sword but not scissors, in
>   Bengali we call it kAtAri). And, in her left hands she holds a kapAla (skull)
>   and a padma (lotus)**..... In her head, MahAdeva himself (Akshovya)
>   resides in the form of a nAga (serpent).
>
> **Goddess TAra's dhyAnam from Nila Tantram, Patala 4.**

So, Goddess TArA is not holding scissors in any of her four hands at all.

Comment: Oh. So it was a "Kartrika", as you said, similar to scissors. Thank you so much. I was also thinking how could God hold an object so modern that would not even suit the iconography. Your answer cleared me of my doubts.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Yes its kartrika and no its not similar to scissors. When scissors have two sharp edges the kartrika has only one. Its much like a sword , some portion of it is of the shape of a half moon the rest is like that of sword. BTW how are u? You don't seem to post much these days.